# Prevent page auto Reloading using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website and when opening the page, reloading automatically infinite times.

How do I stop the page from reloading automatically infinite times?

This code is doing that reloading , when i commented this code the reloading not reload the page.
 but i don't know how fix it .
any advise .

> This is the html code

```html
<h1>
                Edit Project</h1>
            <div id="Div3" class="entryRow">
                <div class="title">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Select Developer"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="entry">                

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldeveloperForEdit" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" DataTextField="DeveloperName" DataValueField="DeveloperPK">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Developer" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=MyCBEntities"
                        DefaultContainerName="MyCBEntities" EntitySetName="Developer" Select="it.[DeveloperPK], it.[DeveloperName]"
                        OrderBy="it.[DeveloperName]">
                    </asp:EntityDataSource>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Select Project&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjects" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjects_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
//here this control <cc1:CascadingDropDown code when i comment it the reloading not happened, here the issue how fix it
                    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="CascProjects" PromptText="Select Project" PromptValue="0" Enabled="true"
                        ServiceMethod="GetProjectsListByDeveloper" ServicePath="~/WebServ/MyCBWebService.asmx"
                        Category="selProject" TargetControlID="ddlProjects" runat="server" ParentControlID="ddldeveloperForEdit">
                    </cc1:CascadingDropDown>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="msg">
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateDevelopers();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

     private void PopulateDevelopers()
    {
        using (var db = new MyCBEntities())
        {

            if (ddlDevelopers.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlDevelopers.ClearSelection();
                ddlDevelopers.Items.Clear();
            }
            var developers = db.Developer.OrderBy(z => z.DeveloperName).ToList();
            ddlDevelopers.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Developer", "0-1"));
            foreach (var developer in developers)
            {
                ddlDevelopers.Items.Add(new ListItem(developer.DeveloperName,  developer.DeveloperPK.ToString()));

            }
            ddlDevelopers.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
    }
```

> This is the ServiceMethod="GetProjectsListByDeveloper"

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetProjectsListByDeveloper(string knownCategoryValues, string category)
    {


        StringDictionary kv = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues);



        MyCBEntities db = new MyCBEntities();


        string developerIdStr = "";




        if (kv.Count > 0 && kv.ContainsKey("country"))
        {
            developerIdStr = kv["country"];
        }
        else if (kv.Count > 0 && kv.ContainsKey("undefined"))
        {
            developerIdStr = kv["undefined"];
        }

        int developerId;

        int.TryParse(developerIdStr, out developerId);


        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> values =
         new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();


        if (developerId > 0)
        {


            var projectList = db.DevelopersProject.Where(z => z.DeveloperFK == developerId).ToList();

            foreach (var project in projectList)
            {
                values.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(project.ProjectName, project.DeveloperProjectPK.ToString()));
            }
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of cc1:CascadingDropDown?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe I updated the question with code of cc1:CascadingDropDown

Comment: @Alex-TinLe Any advise ?